# Python - Parse INI text (not INI file)

Tags: python, string, ini, configparser

I have a case where I get a string version of an INI file and not the file itself. I am getting it this way from an external source and hence cannot be changed.

Example of the string version:

```
'[DEFAULT]\nScore = 0.1\n\n[dev]\nHost = abc.com\nPort = 0000\n\n[qa]\nHost = xyz.com\nEsPort = 1000\n\n[main]\nHost = pqr.com\nPort = 2000\n'
```

I tried parsing this string using the configParser library in python:

```
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read(my_ini_str)
[]
```

I get back nothing with the read function. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE - Forgot to add that I am using Python 2.

Comment: [`read_string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string)?

Comment: See my comment to the response from jwodder

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`read_string()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_string) method is for.

> Parse configuration data from a string.

Hence:

```
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read_string(my_ini_str)
```

Comment: I tried this but got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 728, in read_string
    sfile = io.StringIO(string)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: Seems like that function exists in Python 3 but not in Python 2.

Comment: @activelearner: Based on that error message, you need to decode your string to `unicode` first.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `read_string` in order to parse a string.

then you have to use getters on "config" object, such as :

```
>>> config.get('dev', 'Host')
'abc.com'
```

or

```
>>> config.getfloat(config.default_section, 'Score')
0.1
```